# Using textLength attribute

Tags: svg

I have segments of text that I want to put into a fixed 80px width, and I'm looking for the best way to implement fall-back if they don't quite fit (they will all be very close so I expect spacing can be used to make corrections).

I looked at the documentation for the textLength attribute but found it very hard to understand -- and the [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/textLength) don't help at all. Specifying the pixel width on a text element garbles the text in Firefox and does nothing in my Chrome.

An article at [More Robust SVG Text](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/more-robust-svg-text-with-lengthadjust-and-font-size-adjust) gave examples in 'em' units, but I haven't found any official documentation to explain why that works when pixels do not. Using that method helps in Firefox (although it's ignored on tspan), but is totally ignored in Chrome.

```
<svg width="570px" height="310px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>
text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
</style>

<rect  x="115" y="180" width="80"  height="80" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
<text x="155" y="180"  textLength="80">
<tspan dy="1.2em" x="155" >Elizabeth</tspan>
<tspan dy="1.1em" x="155" >Taylor</tspan>
<tspan dy="1.1em" x="155" >(c1731&#x2013;1783)</tspan>
</text>
</svg>
```

Can someone explain how to use it in a portable way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the behaviour of `textLength` when there are `<tspan>` elements is a little buggy on all(?) browsers.

Firefox's behaviour is correct I think, and makes sense if you leave all the `<tspan>` elements in their default position, and don't move them.

*(View this in Firefox)*

```html
<svg width="570px" height="310px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>
text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
</style>

<rect  x="115" y="180" width="80"  height="80" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
<text x="155" y="180" textLength="80">
<tspan dy="1.2em" x="155" >Elizabeth</tspan>
<tspan dy="1.1em" x="155" >Taylor</tspan>
<tspan dy="1.1em" x="155">(c1731&#x2013;1783)</tspan>
</text>

<text x="155" y="180" textLength="80">
<tspan>Elizabeth</tspan>
<tspan>Taylor</tspan>
<tspan>(c1731&#x2013;1783)</tspan>
</text>
</svg>
```

It is resizing all the text so that its total length is 80px.

Perhaps you wanted each `<tspan>` to be length 80px?  You don't say. The reason that isn't happening is because `textLength` is not a style property. Thus it isn't inherited by the `<tspan>` elements.  If you want that, you have to set that attribute on every `<tspan>`.

```html
<svg width="570px" height="310px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>
text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
</style>

<rect  x="115" y="180" width="80"  height="80" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
<text x="155" y="180">
<tspan dy="1.2em" x="155" textLength="80">Elizabeth</tspan>
<tspan dy="1.1em" x="155" textLength="80">Taylor</tspan>
<tspan dy="1.1em" x="155" textLength="80">(c1731&#x2013;1783)</tspan>
</text>
</svg>
```

Unfortunately, this only works on Chrome currently, but not on Firefox.

Basically it seems that Chrome only likes `textLength` when it is on a leaf child element. And Firefox only likes it when it is on a parent text element.

You don't say exactly what you want, but my recommendation would be to avoid `<tspan>` and use proper `<text>` elements for every line, if you want the behaviour to match on all browsers.

*(The following example looks the same on Chrome and Firefox)*

```html
<svg width="570px" height="310px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>
text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
</style>

<rect  x="115" y="180" width="80"  height="80" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
<text x="155" y="180" dy="1.2em" textLength="80">Elizabeth</text>
<text x="155" y="180" dy="2.3em" textLength="80">Taylor</text>
<text x="155" y="180" dy="3.4em" textLength="80">(c1731&#x2013;1783)</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'd just arrived at the conclusion that Firefox was applying it to the whole text, but I still don't see why a textLength="13em" seems to work as I wanted. I hadn't considered using 'text' as you describe. What's the pros-and-cons of that versus tspan for this purpose (I wanted each segment bound by 80px)?

Comment: OK. Just tried all the examples and it looks like I have misunderstood what textLength does. Rather than restrict the text when it's too long, it set a fixed length. Your last example, Paul, the only one that works in all cases, expands my text to fix the rectangle. All I want to do is squeeze the text a little if it overruns the 80px limit.

Comment: I suspected that was the case.  Unfortunately SVG doesn't have a way to do that.